# Python script to parse text file and execute inline python code

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to create a script that could do the following:

```
infile = open("input.txt", "r")
outfile = open("output.txt", "w")
print ("Starting file transformation...")

for line in infile:

    # If the line is not encapsulated in between two markers: 
    # //START_PY & //END_PY then print the line verbatim. If 
    # it is between the markers then execute the inline python code

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

So an input.txt like the following:

---

```
Hello World

//START_PY

    for count in range(1,2):
        print ("More Hello World");

//END_PY

Even More Hello World
```

---

This would output the following:

```
Hello World

More Hello World

More Hello World

Even More Hello World
```

I could create an intermediate python script and execute that from within the parent script. Is there a way to do this in one pass i.e. directly create the output file?

Comment: you can use exec() to evaluate a string as if it were code

Answer (score 0):

It can be done withe the help of abstract syntax trees "ast" module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> # let's assume you already parsed your code sections
>>> code_text = "for count in range(2):\n\tprint('[%d] More hello worlds' % count)\n"
>>> po = ast.parse(code_text)
>>> co = compile(po, "<unknown>", "exec")
>>> namespace = {}
>>> exec(co, namespace)
[0] More hello worlds
[1] More hello worlds
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! So this is actually not executing the string but rather parsed code string? Any benefit to doing this than giving exec() the string itself?

Comment: Depending on your requirements might not be needed. AST allows you to programatically modify/verify your code sections before execution by for example enforcing certain syntax template to be used (if your code sections are coming from external sources over which you don't have control).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! Here is what I did and it works well. Would love to learn of any better ways of doing it.

```
infile = open("input.txt", "r")

lines = infile.readlines()

create_inline_script = 0
script_str = ""
start_delim = "//START_PY"
end_delim = "//END_PY"

for line in lines:
    if create_inline_script == 1:
        if (re.search(end_delim,line)):
            exec (script_str)    
            create_inline_script = 0
            script_str = ""
        else:
            script_str += line   
    elif (re.search(start_delim,line)):
        create_inline_script = 1
    else:
        print (line)

infile.close()
```